# How to get the Character that is before the cursor in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Let's say I have the following `UITextView` object:

```
var textView = UITextView()
textView.text = "Hello World!"
```

Now let's say I don't want to allow the user to delete the "W" character while editing it. How could I know which character is before the cursor (or selected by it)?

I'm looking for something that would work like this:

```
if textView.characterBeforeCursor() != "W" {
   textView.deleteBackward()
}
```

or... (when the user selects the "W" character):

```
if textView.selectedTextContains("W") == false {
   textView.deleteBackward()
}
```

What approach should I use to accomplish this?

Comment: What about checking the length of 'W` before and after the modification and return the previous value of the `textView` in case of difference values ?

Comment: I thought about that possibility, but it looks like a "hack". I wonder if there's the "right way" of doing that.

Comment: have you tried - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield ? You can do some calculations over the range and have control over input too. perfact shot for you.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to know if the first letter of words (separated by spaces) is about to be changed? and prevent that? or just "W" in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea, not fully tested, but seems to work... Just grab the character about to be acted upon and block backspace if its the target... Also with regard to selection of text, if the selection contains the target at all, we block new text.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func characterBeforeCursor() -> String? {
        // get the cursor position
        if let cursorRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
            // get the position one character before the cursor start position
            if let newPosition = textView.position(from: cursorRange.start, offset: -1) {
                let range = textView.textRange(from: newPosition, to: cursorRange.start)
                return textView.text(in: range!)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (characterBeforeCursor() == "W") {
            let char = text.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
            if (isBackSpace == -92) {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
        else {
            if let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
                let selectedText = textView.text(in: range)
                if (selectedText!.contains("W")) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThiagoAM - now its updated to work even with selection

Comment: @ThiagoAM - there was a bug, but it works now, I think its good, check it out

Comment: Great answer! That's what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @ThiagoAM did you even try the other shorter answers or at least read them?

Comment: @ThiagoAM a pleasure!

Comment: Is Emojis broken if using this way?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
let forbiddenLetter = "W" 

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    guard let txt = textView.text, let txtRange = Range(range, in: txt) else {
        return false
    }

    let subString: Substring = txt[txtRange]

    return !subString.contains(forbiddenLetter)
}
```

In the code above `let txt = textView.text` is just for simplicity, we could keep force-unwrapping `textView.text!` since the `.text` property is designed never returns `nil` for a non-nil UITextView.

By `let txtRange = Range(range, in: txt)` we get a variable of type `Range<String.Index>` instead of the vanilla NSRange that `range` is. By doing so we can get the Substring of `txt` that the textView is about to change.

Finally, the result of checking whether or not the `subString` contains the `forbiddenLetter`, is returned.

---

This snippet would prevent deleting `W` by using:

- Backspace key <kbd>⌫</kbd>
- Deleting selection
- Pasting over selection
- Autocorrect (from the popup)

Comment: found the issue, your solution uses UITextField delegate methods, not UITextView

Comment: @Woodstock thank you for pointing that out, I've updated the answer

Comment: It's a gorgeous solution, should be marked as the answer. Well Done, could you annotate your code to show the logic?